# PHPUnit does not run its tests

Tags: php, phpunit, eclipse-pdt

I am following the examples in the PHPUnit manual. See the two Test files below. I am running the tests in Eclipse PDT with PTI installed. I see the following problems:

- When running DependencyFailureTest, it does not recognize it as being a test. Is does not run anything.
- When running MultipleDependenciesTest, it is running and mentions that all three test cases pass, as it should. However, if I then change the expected outcome in the function testConsumer into array('first', 'third'), it still mentions that all test cases pass, although one of them should clearly fail. Also, when I change one of the assertions into `$this->assertTrue(FALSE);`, I expect a failed and a skipped test case, but again all test cases pass.

Has anyone experienced something similar, and solved this?

**DependencyFailureTest**

```
<?php
class DependencyFailureTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testOne()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(FALSE);
    }

    /**
     * @depends testOne
     */
    public function testTwo()
    {
    }
￼￼￼￼￼￼}
?>
```

**MultipleDependenciesTest**

```
<?php
class MultipleDependenciesTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testProducerFirst()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
        return 'first';
    }

    public function testProducerSecond()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
        return 'second';
    }

    /**
     * @depends testProducerFirst
     * @depends testProducerSecond
     */
    public function testConsumer()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(
            array('first', 'second'),
            func_get_args()
        );
    }
}￼￼￼
?>
```

Comment: I think that your test are ok! Do you tried run in command line? What's error in log?

Comment: Hmmm, I now try to reproduce my own problem, and it seems to be working as it should. :-S No clue what is different now, though.

Comment: What's is stack trace from plugin?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Do you mean the console output when I run the test? If not, where should I look?

Comment: I said about PDI in Eclipse

Comment: I still have no clue what 'stack trace of a plugin' means. Can you please explain what this is, and where I could find it?

Comment: Can you try MakeGood (available on marketplace and p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org)? PTI is a little bit outdated.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I should try that again. I tried installing MakeGood, but it required a lot of installation magic, one of them was installing XDebug, that also required a lot of installation magic. I was unable to install it all yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer yet, only some black magic voodoo. I noticed that for running it in the command line, I need to include the class under test.

```
<?php

require_once ('path/to/Car.php')

class CarTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
...
```

For running it in PTI, I mention the file in the Bootstrap file in the PHPUnit preferences. Therefore, this `reuire_once` statement is not necessary. But worse however, this `require_once` statement causes the test not to run!

Something strange that I noticed is that at one time, my tests were not running, even without the `require_once` statement. In the PHPUnit preferences, I had the option Do not check for equal namespaces while searching for php/test case classes enabled. I disabled it, and it worked. I enabled it again, and it still worked.

[image: Eclipse PHPUnit preferences]

Answer (score 0):

Phpunit doesnot show any thing (run 0/0)

> Console Error:
> Fatal error: Declaration of PHPUnitLogger::addFailure(Test $test, AssertionFailedError $e, $time): void must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener::addFailure(PHPUnit\Framework\Test
> $test, PHPUnit\Framework\AssertionFailedError $e, float $time): void in
> C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\phpunit_printer\PHPUnitLogger.php(415): eval()'d code on line 1

```
TestCase

<?php
namespace PHPUnit\Framework;

use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

class SeleniumTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    protected $webDriver;

    public function setUp()
    {
        // system . property_exists("Facebook\WebDriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriver", "C:\rc\geckodriver\geckodriver");
        // System . set("Webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\rc\geckodriver\geckodriver");
        $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities::firefox());
        $this->webDriver->manage()
            ->window()
            ->maximize();
        $this->webDriver->get('http://localhost/farmer/login');
        // $this->webDriver->get("www.gmail.com");
    }

    public function testLoginPass()
    {
        $this->webDriver->get('http://localhost/farmer/login');
        $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('username'))->sendKeys(' correct');
        $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('password'))->sendKeys('password');
        $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('btn-login'))->click();
        $content = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::tagName('body'))->getText();
        $this->assertContains('Dashboard', $content);
    }

    public function testLoginFail()
    {
        $this->webDriver->get('http://localhost/farmer/login');
        $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('mobile'))->sendKeys("800000000000");
        $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('password'))->sendKeys("8000000000");
        $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('btn-login'))->click();
        $content = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('help-block'))->getText();
        $this->assertContains('Your Credential Doesnot Match.Please Try Again !!', $content);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->webDriver->quit();
    }
}

?>
```

[While MakeGood is working Properly in Eclipse (Everything is OK)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A52G0.png)

MAKEGOOD result